# CouchDB Attachments Cannot be Opened

Tags: curl, couchdb, attachment, binary-data

I start with a document located at 
`localhost:5984/categories/Jan`
with the following data:

```
{
  "_id": "Jan",
  "_rev": "4-2c0b1c27daca6d2a3c375b0f879a8967",
  "name": "Jan",
}
```

I want to upload a pdf to this document, so I give the following curl command:

```
curl -vX PUT 'http://localhost:5984/categories/Jan/example.pdf?rev=4-2c0b1c27daca6d2a3c375b0f879a8967' -d@example.pdf -H "ContentType: application/pdf"
```

And I get this response:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5984 (#0)
> PUT /categories/Jan/example.pdf?rev=4-2c0b1c27daca6d2a3c375b0f879a8967 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5984
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> ContentType: application/pdf
> Content-Length: 10944067
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< Server: MochiWeb/1.0 (Any of you quaids got a smint?)
< Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 07:48:21 GMT
< Connection: close
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0
< X-Couch-Request-ID: d509f366b8
< Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/18)
< Location: http://localhost:5984/categories/Jan/example.pdf
< Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 07:48:23 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 66
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
<
{"ok":true,"id":"Jan","rev":"5-4ae0ca0bd54d63b9ac45e3e57785648d"}
```

This appears to me to be a successful upload. However, when I visit the url
`localhost:5984/categories/Jan/example.pdf`, there are two problems:

- instead of opening in the browser, I'm asked to download the attachment
- when I download and open the attachment, it says the data can't be read.

This happens for other content-types besides pdfs (I've also tried w/ a png).  Can anyone let me know what might be going wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Which version are you using? after the load do you have an "_attachments" attribute in the document?

Comment: Sorry,  I see in the trace that you are using last version 2.1.1

Comment: @JuanjoRodríguez  I'm also using the same code on another computer (a Mac) that must use version 1 of Couch.  Files upload successfully now, but when I try to open them in the browser the file doesn't open properly.  Is "_attachments" necessary for version 1?  Could you give an example of a curl command with a data binary body that uses it successfully?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think so, it is the way that the attachment is stored in the document: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/document/common.html#attachments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be the ***ContentType*** header that you have specified during the attachment creation.

The correct header name is **Content-Type**

The curl command should be:

```
curl -vX PUT 'http://localhost:5984/categories/Jan/example.pdf?rev=4-2c0b1c27daca6d2a3c375b0f879a8967' -d@example.pdf -H "Content-Type: application/pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give you the bounty when the time limit is reached.